# Emulator memory access WP7

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, emulation

I make the download of a file and save it with isolated storage.. I want to know if i have a way to see the file in the memory of the emulator.. theres some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isolated storage in Emulator is just like an isolated storage on a real device from IO point of view. For example, to save a text file to an isolated storage call:

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

//create new file
using (StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("myFile.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, myIsolatedStorage)))
{
    string someTextData = "This is some text data to be saved in a new text file in the IsolatedStorage!";
    writeFile.WriteLine(someTextData);
    writeFile.Close();
}
```

To read it from isolated storage:

```
IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("myFile.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
{    //Visualize the text data in a TextBlock text
    this.text.Text = reader.ReadLine();
}
```

Examples are provided by [windowsphonegeek](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-read-and-save-text-files)